# Keycloak Refresh Token implementation with ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spring-boot, nginx, keycloak

**Current tech stack:** ReactJS, Nginx, SpringBoot, Keycloak.

Earlier in place of **nginx**, **Node+Redis** was used to implement refresh token.

**Old Implementation:** if user is active, before expiry time of 5/10 min node will call refresh token API.

Now after Node is replaced with nginx. I'm unable to figure out how to implement refresh token with the current tech stack or any other tools/plugin is required ?